# Removing large number of strings from a huge list

Tags: c++, performance, list

I have a **large list of strings** stored in one huge memory block (usually there is 100k+ or even 1M+ of them). These are actually hashes, so the alphabet of the strings is limited to A-F0-9 and each string is exactly 32 bytes long (so its stored 'compressed'). I will call this list the **main list** from now on.

I want to be able to **remove items** from the main list. This will be usually done in bulks, so i get a large list (about 100 to 10k usually) of hashes which i need to find in this list and remove them. At the end of this operation there cannot be any empty blocks in the large memory block, so i need to take that into account. It is not guaranteed that all of the items will be in the main list, but none will be there multiple times. No rellocation can be done, the main block will always stay the same size.

**The naive approach** of iterating through the main list and checking if given hash shall be removed of course **works, but is a bit slow**. Also there is a bit too much moving of small memory blocks, because every time when a hash is flagged for removal i rewrite it with the last element of the main list, thus satisfying the condition of no empty blocks. This of course creates **thousands of small memcpy's** which in turn slow the thing down more because i get tons of cache misses.

**Is there a better approach?**

Some important notes:

- the main list is not sorted and i cannot waste time sorting it, this
  is a limitation imposed by the whole project and rewriting it so the
  list is always sorted is not an option (it might not even be
  possible)
- memory is not really a problem, but the less is used the better
- i can use STL, but not boost

Comment: Are you SURE it's not worth sorting the list? Sorting a 1M block of stuff (32 bytes each) shouldn't be terribly hard - and it changes your O(n) algorithm for search for ones to remove to O(log2(n)) - so on average half a million searches goes to on average 20 searches. Surely that's worthwhile? Assuming of course this is something you wish to do more than once.

Comment: Why are you storing strings to begin with? 32 hex digits can be stored in 32*4 = 128 bit, which decreases memory consumption (and by extension, improves cache utilization and speeds up comparisons) by a pretty significant factor. If you're bound to a string-based API, you can still (very easily) convert as you receive and are asked for strings.

Comment: is it possible to use a hash set?

Comment: You will 'waste' a lot less time sorting this and using a better data structure than is spent in this brute force garbage collection, however optimized.  I think without a better understanding of the constraints imposed by the project, it's going to be hard for people to get over that.

Comment: @delnan Using binary instead of hex characters gains a factor of exactly two.  (But it could still be worth it, especially for the comparison spead---16 bytes, and most modern machines can easily compare 8 bytes at a time, if he treats each entry as `uint64_t[2]`, rather than `char[32]`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze True, but a factor of two is pretty significant in my book ;)

Comment: @delnan Good suggestion, thanks, will do that.

Comment: @delnan When you're dealing with that many elements, it probably is.  Particularly, as I said, when it comes to comparing; he shouldn't have that much problem with locality anyway, if he does the removals correctly, but doing a `memcmp` on 32 bytes is a lot slower than comparing two `uint64_t`, without a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's what I'd do if I absolutely had to optimize the hell out of this.
I'm assuming order doesn't matter, which seems to be the case as you (IIUC) remove items by swapping them with the last item.

- Store 128 bit integers (however you represent them, either your compiler supports them natively or you use a small array of 32/64 bit integers) instead of 32-char strings. See my comment on the question.
- Roll my own hash set of 128 bit integers. Note that you can optimize *a lot* here if you're willing to think a bit, make some assumption, and get down 'n dirty. Some notes:

  - You only need to store the hashes themselves (for collision resolution), and a bit or two of metadata to identify deleted/unused slots. Have a look at what existing hash tables do if you're unsure how to guarantee correctness. I figure it's even simpler if you only ever delete (not add) after building the hash set. Though I think you could even do without that metadata if you had a value that's not a valid hash to denote empty slots, but this way removal is easier (just flip a bit, instead of overwriting 128 bit).
  - You don't need a hash function, as your inputs are already integers. You just need to do what every hash tables does anyway: Take the hashes modulo 2^n to derive an index that's not freaking huge. Choose n such that the load factor (the percentage of table entries used) is reasonable (< 2/3 seems standard). Choosing a power of makes the modulo operation cheaper (masking off bits via binary AND), and allows you to just do it on the lower 32 or 64 bit (ignoring the rest).
  - Choosing a collision resolution strategy is hard. I'd probably go with [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable#Open_addressing) with linear probing, as first attempt. It *may* work badly, but if your input hashes are any good, this seems unlikely. There's also a probing scheme that factors in more and more of the bits you originally cut off, used by [CPython's `dict`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d12785ecca72/Objects/dictobject.c#l113).

Now, this is a lot more work and maintenance burden than using off-the-shelf solutions. I wouldn't advise it unless this really is as performance-critical as it sounds in your description.
If C++11 is an option, and your compiler's `unordered_set` is any good, maybe you should just use it and save yourself most of the hassle (but be aware that this probably increases memory requirements). You still need to specialize `std::hash` and `std::equal_to` or `operator==`. Alternative supply your own `Hash` and `KeyEqual` for `unordered_set`, but that probably doesn't offer any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Two things might help.  First, at least sort the list of items
to be removed; that way, you can use a binary search
(`std::lower_bounds`) on it.  Second, keep two pointers:
a source and a destination.  If the source points to something
not in the list to be removed, copy it to the destination, and
advance both.  If the source points to something to be removed,
just advance the source pointer, without copying.  There should
never be a reason to copy an entry more than once.